# Not able to generate jar file through terminal for apex SOAP web service

Tags: soap-api, java

I am trying to generate jar file for apex SOAP web service through terminal with command -

> java -classpath
>   force-wsc-40.1.1.jar;ST-4.0.1.jar;antlr-runtime-3.4_2.jar;tools.jar
>   com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc AccountManagerSOAPService_wsdl.xml
>   AccountManager.jar

But I am getting error -

> C:\Users\Rohit\wsc-scratch6350799437671588252tmp\com\sforce\soap\AccountManagerSOAPService\EntityParticle.java:1496:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>           setReferenceTo((com.sforce.soap.AccountManagerSOAPService.RelationshipReferenceTo)__typeMapper.readObject(__in,
>   _lookupTypeInfo("ReferenceTo", "http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/memb/Accoun
>   tManagerSOAPService","ReferenceTo","http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/memb/AccountManagerSOAPService","RelationshipReferenceTo",0,1,true),
>   com.sforce.soap.AccountManagerSOAPService.RelationshipRefe
>   renceTo.class));

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: Might be related to this known issue [Generated WSDL for Apex webservices is malformed](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000eatxQAA&title=generated-wsdl-for-apex-webservices-is-malformed) where the workaround is to manually add some types into the WSDL before you do the code generation.

Comment: Thanks a lot @KeithC, the link shared by you helped me in fixing this issue.

Comment: Cool; you should be able to accept your own answer in a day or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding below mentioned definition to

```
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/<className>/<webserviceName>">
```

tag in web service WSDL file,I am able to generate jar file.

```
<xsd:complexType name="SearchLayoutButtonsDisplayed"> 
<xsd:sequence> 
<xsd:element name="applicable" type="xsd:boolean"/> 
<xsd:element name="buttons" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tns:SearchLayoutButton"/> 
</xsd:sequence> 
</xsd:complexType> 

<xsd:complexType name="SearchLayoutButton"> 
<xsd:sequence> 
<xsd:element name="apiName" type="xsd:string"/> 
<xsd:element name="label" type="xsd:string"/> 
</xsd:sequence> 
</xsd:complexType> 

<xsd:complexType name="SearchLayoutFieldsDisplayed"> 
<xsd:sequence> 
<xsd:element name="applicable" type="xsd:boolean"/> 
<xsd:element name="fields" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tns:SearchLayoutField"/> 
</xsd:sequence> 
</xsd:complexType> 

<xsd:complexType name="SearchLayoutField"> 
<xsd:sequence> 
<xsd:element name="apiName" type="xsd:string"/> 
<xsd:element name="label" type="xsd:string"/> 
<xsd:element name="sortable" type="xsd:boolean"/> 
</xsd:sequence> 
</xsd:complexType> 

<xsd:complexType name="JunctionIdListNames"> 
<xsd:sequence> 
<xsd:element name="names" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xsd:string"/> 
</xsd:sequence> 
</xsd:complexType> 

<xsd:complexType name="RelationshipReferenceTo"> 
<xsd:sequence> 
<xsd:element name="referenceTo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xsd:string"/> 
</xsd:sequence> 
</xsd:complexType> 

<xsd:complexType name="RecordTypesSupported"> 
<xsd:sequence> 
<xsd:element name="recordTypeInfos" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tns:RecordTypeInfo"/> 
</xsd:sequence> 
</xsd:complexType> 

<xsd:complexType name="RecordTypeInfo"> 
<xsd:sequence> 
<xsd:element name="available" type="xsd:boolean"/> 
<xsd:element name="defaultRecordTypeMapping" type="xsd:boolean"/> 
<xsd:element name="master" type="xsd:boolean"/> 
<xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/> 
<xsd:element name="recordTypeId" type="tns:ID" nillable="true"/> 
</xsd:sequence> 
</xsd:complexType>
```

The link shared by Keith helped me in resolving this issue.
Please find below link to know more about this issue-
[https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000eatxQAA&title=generated-wsdl-for-apex-webservices-is-malformed](http://Generated%20WSDL%20for%20Apex%20webservices%20is%20malformed)